# Why is user-agent Python-urllib rejected?

Tags: bug

HTTP GET requests with `User-Agent` header starting with `Python-urllib` are rejected by stackoverflow.com. For example this fails with 403 Forbidden error:

```
curl -s -A Python-urllib/3.4 stackoverflow.com -w "%{http_code}\n"
```

More examples:

```
for agent in Python-urllib python-urllib Python-urlli ython-urllib; do
    curl -s -o /dev/null -A $agent stackoverflow.com -w "$agent -> %{http_code}\n"
done
```

Output:

```
Python-urllib -> 403
python-urllib -> 200
Python-urlli -> 200
ython-urllib -> 200
```

That is, the problem seems to be with a literal `Python-urllib` at the beginning of User-Agent.

Other Stack Exchange sites don't seem to do this.
The same user agent string works fine for example with Server Fault, Math, Code Review.

I stumbled upon this while using a [Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33745205/641955) that used `urllib` to fetch URLs. By default it uses `Python-urllib/3.4` as the value of `User-Agent`, and I noticed that the script works with other sites on the network except with Stack Overflow. It's not a big deal (I switched to a different library instead of `urllib`). Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Maybe [Oded](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) hates Python?

Comment: It's not difficult to change the agent header on a request like that, either.  Perhaps this was meant to catch the lazy who did mass amounts of requests in Python?

Comment: Maybe it has something to with the white and blacklisting of user-agents that seems to exist: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37231/why-does-the-stack-overflow-sitemap-xml-use-a-user-agent-whitelist-instead-of-a

Comment: It doesn't seem to block some other popular programmatic user-agents (e.g. curl and python requests). Interestingly, I see that it does reject perl's lwp-request with a 403.

Comment: Slightly related, but I get `403 Forbidden` errors whenever I try to access a `*.meta.stackexchange.com` site using `https` (`http` doesn't seem to work for anything stack exchange for me...)

Comment: Wild guess: if CloudFlare's currently in use (not sure), maybe their abuse filters have automatically learned to treat the default Python urllib agent as suspicious, rather than this being a deliberate block.

Comment: That seems like a good wild guess: `<title>Access denied | stackoverflow.com used CloudFlare to restrict access</title>` with the urllib default user-agent, `<title>Stack Overflow</title>` without!

Comment: First, python, second, scrapers.  That's my guess.

Comment: This broke my RSS reader, which only hits my SO feed every 30 minutes so is in no way abusive. I don't know when exactly it happened, but I think it was sometime in the last month. I can obviously work around it, but as it's been fine for years, I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the same outputs, I think this problem is solved.

Running

```
for agent in Python-urllib python-urllib Python-urlli ython-urllib; do
    curl -s -o /dev/null -A $agent stackoverflow.com -w "$agent -> %{http_code}\n"
done
```

I get

```
Python-urllib -> 301
python-urllib -> 301
Python-urlli -> 301
ython-urllib -> 301
```